# htaccess to redirect, replacing one character in the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Okay here goes.

We created an image library on DVD from InDesign which has a URL on the page, from a PDF file the link is click-able, so users can download the image for use on their own website etc etc.

A problem has occurred where in SOME instances the link has changed from

```
http://example.com/2014-Image-Bank/Accessories-Folder/JPEG/image_1.jpg
```

to

```
http://example.com/2014-Im%ADage-Bank/Accessories-Folder/JPEG/image_1.jpg
```

The %AD being an overscore(?) character which indesign seems to have sprinkled in randomly...(?)

As the DVD's are all duplicated and ready to be used, I'd like to use .htaccess to simply redirect the links omitting the %AD.

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 https://mysite.com/2014-Im¯age-Bank/(.*)     
https://mysite.com/2014-Image-Bank/$1
```

but it's not working

I've tried using both Im¯age and Im%ADage as I've read that .htaccess looks for URLs as they are encoded.

Comment: Unicode `U+00AD` is not an “overscore”, but a soft hyphen.

Comment: Your URL shows `%20` but you're trying to replace `%AD`?

Comment: my bad it is %AD that's the problem will amend post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use hexcode in your rewrite rules** i.e.: `\xAD`

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*?)\xAD(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,R]
```